# Using the google closure compiler Java API

Tags: java, maven, minify, google-closure-compiler

I would liket to use the [Google Closure-Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) from Java.

I download the compiler from the Maven repository (com.google.javascript.jscomp) but I can't find any documentation on how to use it. I don't want to use command line interface.

Is this still type of usage still supported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Closure-compiler FAQ](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-call-closure-compiler-from-the-java-api) has a very basic overview. The project does support usage of the Java API, but there isn't official documentation.

There are [third party blog posts](http://blog.bolinfest.com/2009/11/calling-closure-compiler-from-java.html) about it however.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will try to find out.